# Using Parse to query by time in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an app that needs to find objects posted to a class on parse based on the time they were created. I can get the time range in string format and I can change that to any format. How can I pull down certain ranges from the server that isn't just the entire day. Example: 2:15 until 4:30. I would need all objects created on the database between that time returned. Any ideas?

Comment: check out old forums for answer: https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-querying-objects-by-creation-date

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want certain objects that are created between specific time instances.( for example between 2:15 and 4:30). If I am right, then you can use the Parse query and its predicate  whereKey : greaterThan: ([PFQuery Class references](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html). So the only thing that you have to do is giving the date format with hours and minutes. Then Parse will return the object based on your date predicate. Hope this helps.

Regards.